# Installing Git from source into /usr

Tags: git

I previously installed Git from source successfully into `/usr` under Kubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 64-bit.

At a later time, I updated Git with `~/git$ git pull` and then installed as before, using the instructions in `INSTALL`. However, Git did not install to `/usr` -- the updated version of Git is in `~/git`. I tried both sets of instructions in the `INSTALL` file and included the `prefix` argument in all cases.

How can I install Git into `/usr`?